# set /p reads ctrl+c as input instead of terminating the script

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
:gethostname
set /p hostname= Enter the HOST NAME:
call :TRIM2 %hostname% hostname

:TRIM2
SET %2=%1
goto y

:y
if "%hostname%"=="" (
echo Invalid hostname name1 
VERIFY > nul
goto gethostname
)
if errorlevel 1 (
echo Invalid hostname name2 
VERIFY > nul
goto gethostname
)
```

In the above code if i try to terminate the batch (ctrl+c) on bellow particular line.

```
ENTER the HOST NAME:
```

The script reads ctrl+c as an input and displays

```
Invalid hostname name1
```

How to avoid this and terminate batch on ctrl+c.
The above behaviour is same even if i remove the trim part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works for me.  Are you running this script directly from an ordinary command window?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Ya I am running on ordinary command window

Comment: It also works on my 64bit Windows 7 machine without problem. What Windows version are you using?

Comment: I have noticed that `<Ctrl-Break>` can sometimes work when `<Ctrl-C>` does not. Not sure if it will help in your case.

Answer (score 1):

While this does not completely suppress this behaviour, minimizes it and *almost* always the cancel prompt is shown.

```
:gethostname
    set /p "hostname= Enter the HOST NAME:" || goto gethostname
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround - just press `enter` without any text instead of `control-c`

```
:gethostname
set "hostname="
set /p "hostname= Enter the HOST NAME: "
if not defined hostname goto :EOF
call :TRIM2 %hostname% hostname
```