# Why does canceling a Windows batch script with Ctrl+C when prompted by "set /p" give inconsistent behavior?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is the script foo.cmd :

```
@echo off
echo hi
set /p foobar="???"
echo bye
```

When prompted by `set /p`, I press `Ctrl+C` to cancel the script.  At this point, one of several possible things happens, seemingly chosen at random:

1. `^C` appears, followed by `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?`
2. `^C` appears, followed by `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` Then the script terminates, without echoing `bye`.
3. `^C` appears and the script continues, echoing `bye`.

I have also seen cases like 1 or 2 but where the `^C` appears after the "Terminate" prompt or syntax error message.

Actual output of three consecutive attempts:

```
    C:\Users\Me\Documents>foo.cmd
    hi
    ???^CThe syntax of the command is incorrect.
    
    C:\Users\Me\Documents>foo.cmd
    hi
    ???^Cbye
    
    C:\Users\Me\Documents>foo.cmd
    hi
    ???^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
    
    C:\Users\Me\Documents>
```

I found one related question from 7 years ago, but the answers didn't include any explanation of why this happens: [set /p reads ctrl+c as input instead of terminating the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600030/set-p-reads-ctrlc-as-input-instead-of-terminating-the-script)

Comment: I have seen variations of this behavior when editing a batch file while it's running. Clearly cmd.exe is reading the file line by line and can get confused by lines moving around while it's in the middle of executing a command.

Comment: @kindall Thanks for the comment.  In my case, I'm not making any changes to the file while it's running. The only thing I can think of that I might be inadvertently changing is how quickly I press and release Ctrl+C (but I haven't noticed any correlation between my finger speed and what result I get.)

Comment: Actually, I've just seen another case where I see `^C` followed by `bye` and only *then* do I get the `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` message.  And even weirder, I got one with the caret `^`, followed by `bye`, followed by the `C` and then the `Terminate...` message.

Comment: Right now, my best guess is there's something like one thread waiting for input for `set /p`, and another thread checking for Ctrl+C and then canceling the job.  And maybe when I press Ctrl+C it's read by both threads and that kicks off a race between the two.  But I'm really just guessing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set /p` being internal to `cmd` is one of the commands that waits for input. `CTRL+C` meant to stop the process is killing the `set /p` process internally.

As demonstrated by another internal process `timeout` the results are similar, but there is an instance where the `^C` characters are separated by a newline. This batch file simply contains `timeout /t 5` where I then do `CTRL+C` randomly:
[image]

As an attempt to prove that `CTRL+C` is killing the internal processes in your example, then the main process, we can create `CTRL+C` in the script itself (All credit goes to user [`DBenham`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) for the [`exit code`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5859) creating `^C`:

```
@echo off
echo hi
set /p foobar="???" || cmd /c exit -1073741510
echo bye
```

When running this and pressing `Enter` at the `set /p` prompt will then complete the `set` command, where directly after `^C` is issued. The results will remain the same for each run because `CTRL+C` only has the main process to to close:

[image]